# Overwrite laravel package config in own package

Tags: laravel

I have multiple laravel 8 projects with some common logic. For these logics, I am currently creating a package, so that I can use it in all projects and don't have to make changes multiple times.

In all these projects, I am using `spatie/laravel-feed` package, which has a config file `feed.php` to customize the paths/routes. Is there a way to create a centralized config file `feed.php` inside the package? So the hierarchy of config merging should be:

1. vendor/spatie/laravel-feed/config/feed.php
2. vendor/my-package/-my-package/config/feed.php
3. config/feed.php

Using the following in the my-package `ServiceProvider::register` method doesn't work:

```
$this->mergeConfigFrom(
    __DIR__.'/../../config/feed.php', 'feed',
);
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?
I'm currently on the same topic looking for ideas.

Comment: Not really. You could manually overwrite the config in your package service provider.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: For example `config(['app.name' => 'My name'']);` or you set the whole config array `config(['configname' => ['var1' => 1, 'var2' => 'test']]);`

Comment: does that set global config, doesn't it?
Can I only overwrite the config from a specific file? e.g. the config/feed.php file.

Comment: It works exactly like getting the config. After loading, all config files are translated to an array value. So the `app.php` is now inside `config('app')`, the `feed.php` is inside `config('feed')`. You can access it with dot-notation, like `config('app.name')` or  `config('feed.feeds')` and you can set it in the same way: `config(['app.name' => "My new name"])` or  `config(['feed.feeds' => [...]])`